# Need help reading text file into Object

Tags: java

I have created a Person class, with parameters firstname, lastname, and year. I need to figure out how to read input from a text file and create an Array of Persons. Here is what I am trying, based on different sources I pooled from the web.

```
String name = "People.txt";
        Person[] people = new ArrayList<Person>();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(name));
        String line = br.readLine();
        while(line != null)
        {
            people.add(line);
            line = br.readLine();
        }
```

But of course, this isn't working. I doubt its even close to being correct, so I was wondering if you guys have any advice.

Also, the constructor for my Person class is as follows:

```
public Person(String firstName, String lastName, int age){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
    }



The error reads,

`SortingImplementation.java:15: incompatible types
found   : java.util.ArrayList<Person>
required: Person[]
                Person[] people = new ArrayList<Person>();
                                  ^
SortingImplementation.java:20: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method add(java.lang.String)
location: class Person[]
                        people.add(line);
                              ^
Note: SortingMethod.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
2 errors
`
```

Text file is

```
Larry Kim 45
Bob Stuart 51
Nancy Davis 38
John Doe   49
Henry Miles 23
Albert Lee 36
Mary Wing  43
Tony Rich  55
Ally Sneetch  19
Carrie Chrome 77
David Abkenzy 41
Young Old    18
Snow White  70
George Herald 60
Mike Bush 22
Peter Paul 33
Peter Pan 44
Mary Paul 25
Ray Romano 55
```

Well, sweet. You guys are awesome, maybe I'll get to sleep tonight. Been up for literally two days straight trying to get this done, starting to hallucinate. One last problem I am having, and I am sure it is something simple, but I am getting this error.

```
SortingImplementation.java:15: unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("People.txt"));
                                                       ^
SortingImplementation.java:16: unreported exception java.io.IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
                String line = br.readLine();
```

I think it might just have to do with the way I am instantiating, or maybe I don't have the proper header files imported. Here's what I have imported.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.*;
```

Do you guys see anything that might be missing?

Comment: "isn't working" isn't a useful description.  We knew it wasn't working before reading the question (why else would you ask anything?)

Comment: What does the text file look like? Show an example of the text file format.

Comment: Ahhh!!! Someone come back real quick, please! I am so close to being finished, but something like this will keep me staring at it for hours...

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

1. Without changing the `Person` class, after reading the line, you can parse the data into the `firstName`, `lastName`, and `age`, and send these arguments to the constructor.
2. You can add a constructor to `Person` that expects a single, unparsed `String` argument and does all the parsing within the constructor and assigns the initializes the variables from there.

For details on how to do either option, you'd have to show us what the text file looks like exactly.

---

But currently, your problem is that you're trying to add a `String` object to an `ArrayList` of `Person` objects.

You need to do this:

```
people.add(new Person(/*constructor arguments*/));
```

---

Now that you've updated to include the file format, try something like this:

```
while(line != null) {
    String[] lineParts = line.split("\\s+");
    people.add(new Person(lineParts[0],lineParts[1],parseInt(lineParts[2]));
    line = br.readLine();
}
```

---

Doing via an additional `Person` constructor isn't much different.

In your `Person` class, add this constructor:

```
public Person(String s) {
    String[] parts = s.split("\\s+");
    this(parts[0], parts[1], parseInt(parts[2]));
}
```

Then in main, make your `while` loop look like this:

```
while(line != null) {
    people.add(new Person(line));
    line = br.readLine();
}
```

Comment: I would much rather go for option one. If there is some sort of parsing functionality already built in, that would be awesome. Do you know how I can read each component of the lines separately?

Answer (score 1):

You can't just add a line `String` and expect it to magically transform into a `Person`. You need to split each line into separate `String`s then create a person from those `String`

```
    Person[] people = new ArrayList<Person>();  
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(name));
    String line = br.readLine();
    while(line != null)
    {
        people.add(line);
        line = br.readLine();
    }
```

You need to do something like this, Note the change from array to `ArrayList<Person>`

```
    ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();  // Notice change here
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(name));
    String line;
    while((line = br.nextLine()) != null)
    {
        String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+");
        String firstName = tokens[0];
        String lastName = tokens[1];
        int age = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);  // parse String to int

        people.add(new Person(firstName, lastName, age));
    }
```

This is assuming the input text is formatted as follows

> FirstName LastName Age

Also, make sure to wrap everything in a `try/catch` block, or have the method `throws IOException`;

Comment: You had another typo too, I just fixed it for you.  But it appears in some places he has extra spaces between last name and age, so `tokens[2]` may not necessarily work.  `tokens[tokens.size()-1]`?

Comment: Thats what the \\s+ is for

Comment: Oh... you originally had `" "`.

Comment: Also, as I just edited into my post, you'll probably need `parseInt()`